# ListView Data Binding in Xamarin Forms without using GetDashboard button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

On Login or Navigating to Dashboard Page, fetching data from API, I am using an extra button (Show Communities) to fetch my Fetch my Data. here is my code

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="#30af91" Padding="60" VerticalOptions="Center">

<Entry Text="{Binding Username}" Placeholder="Username"/>
<Entry Text="{Binding Password}" IsPassword="True" Placeholder="Password"/>

<Button Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" Text="Login" Clicked="Button_OnClicked"/>

</StackLayout>
```

**Button_OnClicked** only navigate to **Dashboard** page

```
    private async void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Dashboard());
    }
```

**LoginCommand** in LoginViewModel

```
public ICommand LoginCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async() =>
            {
                var accesstoken = await _apiServices.LoginAsync(Username, Password);
                Settings.AccessToken = accesstoken;
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is my **Dashboard** Page

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:epolleasy.ViewModels;assembly=epolleasy"
         x:Class="epolleasy.Views.Dashboard">

<MasterDetailPage.Master>

    <ContentPage Title="Menu">

        <ContentPage.BindingContext>
            <viewModels:DashboardViewModel />
        </ContentPage.BindingContext>

      <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>

          <Button x:Name="BtnActiveForm" Text="Active Forms" Clicked="BtnActiveForm_OnClicked"></Button>
          <Button x:Name="BtnCommunity" Text="My Communities" Clicked="BtnCommunity_OnClicked"></Button>
          <Button x:Name="BtnHistory" Text="Sealed Forms" Clicked="BtnHistory_OnClicked"></Button>

          <Button Text="Logout" Command="{Binding LogoutCommand}" Clicked="Logout_OnClicked"/>

        </StackLayout>
      </ContentPage.Content>

    </ContentPage>

</MasterDetailPage.Master>


</MasterDetailPage>
```

Here is **my Communities** page where i am using an extra button using GetDashboard Command

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:epolleasy.ViewModels;assembly=epolleasy"
         x:Class="epolleasy.Views.DpCommunities">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:DashboardViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
  <ToolbarItem Text="Add New" 
               Icon="add.png"
               Priority="0"
               Clicked="MenuItem_OnClicked"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>


<StackLayout>

    <Button Command="{Binding GetDashboard}" Text="Show Communities"/>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding UserDashboard.Com}"
              HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding CommunityName}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding CommunityUsers.Count}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding FormsCommunity.Count}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>

</StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Here is **GetDashboard** Command in my ViewModel

```
public ICommand GetDashboard
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(async () =>
        {
             var accessToken = Settings.AccessToken;
             UserDashboard = await _apiServices.GetDashboard(accessToken);
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my **UserDashboard** in the same view model.

```
public Dashboard UserDashboard
    {
        get { return _userDashboard; }
        set
        {
            _userDashboard = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

I want to get rid of that **extra button**.

Comment: use the Page's OnAppearing method to fire the data request

Comment: I am confused regarding this. Can you plz guide me? I have to present my this final year project after one hour.

Comment: @UzairNadeem You could at least accept Jason's answer or reply why it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every page has an OnAppearing method that fires when the page is display.  You can use this to load your data instead of having the user click a button.

```
public override async void OnAppearing() {

  base.OnAppearing();

  var accessToken = Settings.AccessToken;
  UserDashboard = await _apiServices.GetDashboard(accessToken);
}
```